# Blender running in background with python script accepting arguments using Flask api

Tags: python

I want to run a flask application with html. I will get inputs from a html form, then put into a python script then save a 3d-model as an object file. To generate the 3d-model, I need blender run in background so I can use `import bpy` in python. I also use the `argparse` package in python to accept input from html form.

The problem happens when I use `argparse` to accept inputs. Below is my code:

```
import subprocess as sp
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/3d-model/')
def form():
    return render_template('body_form.html')

@app.route('/3d-model/', methods=['POST'])
def form_post():
    inputs = request.form
    gender = inputs['gender']
    w = inputs['weight']
    h = inputs['height']
    data_17 = [inputs[f'd{i}'] for i in range(3, 20)]
    data = [w, h] + data_17
    sp.call(['blender', '-b', 'mesh.blend', '--python', 'main.py', '-s', gender, '-l', *data])
    return ','.join(list(map(str,data)))
```

At the last 2nd line, `main.py` accept inputs and generating the model, `-s` accept a string and `-l` accept a list of inputs which is done by setting argparse `-l` with `nargs='+'`. However, when I run it with flask, the following error happens:

```
usage: blender [-h]
blender: error: unrecognized arguments: -b mesh.blend --python main.py -s male -l 88 185 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I also looked at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44733076/passing-arguments-to-a-python-blender-script-through-the-brenda-web-interface), it says I could add `'--'` after `'--python'` command, but this run into
`OSError: Python file "C:\path\to\my\dir\--" could not be opened: No such file or directory`

My question is, how can one accept arguments properly into python script while letting blender run in the background?

(I couldn't find more relevant tags for this question, if you know some please help me to add the tags.)

---

Update: I mistaken the place putting `'--'`, it should be after the script name, for my case after `'main.py'`, but it still gives the below error:

```
blender: error: unrecognized arguments: -b mesh.blend --python main.py -- -s male -l 88 185 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Since you seem to want a totally headless blender for this project, consider: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule

Comment: Hi. If I can build blender as a python module, does that means I don't need to run 'blender --background' before importing bpy?

Comment: The error is coming from your use of argparse in main.py. You're probably doing something like `parser.parse_args()` which passes all Blender's args to argparse, but you should be doing something like `parser.parse_args( sys.argv[sys.argv.index('--')+1:] )` which passes only the args after the `--`. Would need to see your argparse code to say more.

Comment: You're right actually, after I modify the parser it works! Thank you.