# Blender doesn't recognize --python as a command line argument

Tags: python, command-line, linux

I'm running into a weird problem where running blender from the command line will run with the --background flag, but it's not recognizing the --python flag. Any thoughts?

[image]

This is the output of my current directory:
[image].

The script I'm running is the script found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example)

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is strange. It should have worked and those are not Blender's command line options printed after `usage`. Could you please check if using `./blender --factory-startup --background --python ./unit_test_example.py` works correctly? Could it be that you have third-party add-ons or Python packages installed?

Comment: It seems that the printed options are for [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) as seen here: https://bugs.python.org/issue41253

Comment: @RobertGützkow Oh, these are very interesting findings! With the --factory-startup, I still get the same error.

Comment: Your script is probably doing something like `parser.parse_args()` ie. trying to interpret all Blender's arguments as it's own arguments. See eg [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/237076/88681). Post your script.

Comment: My script is this:

```import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a Python script, sys.argv will be all arguments passed to *Blender*. That means if you call a Python functions that expects to "own" all of `sys.argv` it will see all Blender's arguments and get confused because it probably isn't expecting them.

In your case, you call `unittest.main`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main)

> The *argv* argument can be a list of options passed to the program, with the first element being the program name. If not specified or None, the values of sys.argv are used.

So this explains it. Your script is trying to interpret the arguments in sys.argv that belong to Blender as though they belonged to it.

If you don't intend to pass any arguments to your script, you can just pass a fake program name as argv, eg. `unittest.main(argv=['something'])`.

If you do intend to pass arguments, Blender let's you pass your own arguments after `--`. So you would do something like

```
    import sys
    argv = [__file__]  # program name
    if "--" in sys.argv:
        argv += sys.argv[sys.argv.index("--") + 1:]

    unittest.main(argv=argv)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer! Yes, adding ```unittest.main(argv=['something'])``` at the bottom of the python file did the trick!